# subtract Time based on dayname for different zone

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to subtract time/day using a mysql query;

It is something like 02:00 in (GMT-1) on saturday - wednesday 00:59 in (GMT+5)

How can I do this with a sql query? and get result like 3 days 7 hours and 1 minutes

> edit: both days are of same week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates for this work, and thanks to @symcbean I could get it to work with TIMEDIFF

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ('2012-04-15 02:00:00', '-01:00', '+05:00'), '2012-04-12 00:59:00');
```

and for the days hours and minutes:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ('2012-04-15 02:00:00', '-01:00', '+05:00'), '2012-04-12 00:59:00')) / 24), ' days ',
    MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ('2012-04-15 02:00:00', '-01:00', '+05:00'), '2012-04-12 00:59:00')), 24), ' hours ',
    MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ('2012-04-15 02:00:00', '-01:00', '+05:00'), '2012-04-12 00:59:00')), ' minutes') as TIMEDIFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2012-04-07 02:00:00', '-01:00', '00:00')
         - CONVERT_TZ('2012-04-04 00:59:00', '05:00', '00:00')
```

> edit: both days are of same week

Then usually the gap between t1 on wed and t2 on saturday will be the same, since DST shifts are usually applied on Sunday morning. Better to use fixed dates.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, Also what difference would it make if its sunday and thursday instead of given days ?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Not all days are 24 hours long.

Comment: Its giving output null, that is what is not working and thank you for reminding me about the DST shifts I get it now

Comment: I got it to work with timediff but could you help me how can i get the format as no of days: hours : minutes thankyou